# apt ignoring new sources list

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

Recently booted a fresh copy of Raspbian Jessie Lite, after modifying sources.list removing the default mirror, apt still downloads both repos from http://archive.raspbian.org/ and also from my recently added mirror.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following command to find the string raspbian in the apt configuration directory.

`grep raspbian -r /etc/apt/`

There may be tailored entries in directory `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`